# Converting input string of integers to list, then to ints in python?

Tags: python

I want the user to input an integer (6 digits long, so 123456 rather than just 1), and then convert that input into a list, `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`.

I tried this:

```
user_input = list(input("Please enter an 8 digit number")
numbers = [int(i) for i in user_input]
```

I want to be able to perform mathematical stuff with the numbers list, but I keep getting the error "int is not iterable". To be frank, I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing, or sure that the "numbers = [...] " is even necessary, or if it should just be `numbers = user_input`. Trying `numbers = [i for i in user_input]` gets the same error.

Also, I realise I could either run a loop to get each number from the user, or ask them to use commas in between each in order to use the `.split(",")`, but I'd rather not as it seems messy to the user.

Edit: I've been switching things between versions, so sorry for any confusion. This was written in 2.7, though I intend to use Python 3.

Comment: Aren't you in python 2? If so use raw_input instead of input

Comment: Your problem is somewhere else, not in the code your have shown here.

Comment: What version of Python?

Answer (score 1):

In Python 2.7, `input()` returns an integer. To read input as a string use the function `raw_input()` instead. Alternatively, you can switch to Python 3 and where `input()` always returns a string.

Also your solution isn't very neat in case the user is providing numbers with more than 1 digits. For example the string "123" can be interpreted as [1, 2, 3], [12, 3] and so on.

A neat solution is to ask the user to provide the input separated by spaces as follows x_1, x_2, ... x_n

Then your code in Python 3.0 will look like

```
lst = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
```

And for Python 2.7

```
lst = [int(x) for x in raw_input().split()]
```

Answer (score 1):

Function `input` behaves quite differently in Python 2 and in Python 3.

This seems to be Python 2. In Python 2, `input` evaluates entered data as Python code. If only digits are entered, `input` will return one integer. Converting that to a list is not possible, hence the error.

`input` is unsafe and causes many problems, so it is best to avoid it. Use `raw_input` instead.

```
user_input = raw_input("Please enter an 8 digit number: ")
```

This will return a string, e.g. `'12345678'`.

This can be converted to a list. The list will iterate through the string character by character.

```
digits = list(user_input)   # e.g. ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8']
```

But that is not even needed, you can directly do as you did:

```
numbers = [int(i) for i in user_input]   # e.g. [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

---

BTW, the Python 3 version of `input` is the same as Python 2 `raw_input`.